# Getting 403 issue while making request from php curls

Tags: php, libcurl, http-status-code-403, php-curl

I'm Using Curl Request In PHP and try to get the response from server to get the header info for speed test but getting 403 issue. while it's working on local server, i have tried alot but didn't find any solutions. Kindly help me to resolve this issue. --repeat-- I'm Using Curl Requet In PHP and try to get the response from server to get the header info for speed test but getting 403 issue. while it's working on local server, i have tried alot but didn't find any solutions. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

```
$url = "https://www.justdial.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
// Add this line to include headers 
$headers = [    
 "server:nginx",     
"Cookie:Continent=AS; Ak_City=NEWDELHI;",
"x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN",     
"x-akamai-transformed:9 - 0 pmb=mTOE,3mRUM,2",
"date:" . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T"),
"expires:" . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", time() + 600),
"vary:Accept-Encoding",
"continent:AS",
"timing-allow-origin:*",
'Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8',
'Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
"Pragma:akamai-x-cache-on, akamai-x-cache-remote-on,akamai-x-check-cacheable,akamai-x-get-request-id,akamai-x-get-true-cache-key,akamai-x-get-cache-key,akamai-x-serial-no,akamai-x-get-request-id",
'Accept-Encoding:deflate, br',
'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml, application/ld+json, x-shader/x-vertex,application/xml,image/avif,image/webp,v=b3;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language:en-US, en;q=0.9',
'Connection:keep-alive',
'X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:true',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest:document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode:navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-User:?1',
'Sec-Fetch-Site:none', 
];  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
$html = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);  
// Print only the header information 
$headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE); 
$header = substr($html, 0, $headerSize); 
echo $header;
```

**Getting Response**

```
HTTP/2 403 
server: AkamaiGHost
mime-version: 1.0
content-type: text/html
content-length: 265
expires: Fri, 18 Aug 2023 07:07:36 GMT
date: Fri, 18 Aug 2023 07:07:36 GMT
x-cache: TCP_DENIED from a23-59-252-95.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (AkamaiGHost/11.2.2-50274567) (-)
x-cache-key: S/D/5965/800757/000/djskhdk-www.justdial.com/?akamai-transform=9
x-cache-key-extended-internal-use-only: S/D/5965/800757/000/djskhdk-www.justdial.com/?akamai-transform=9 vcd=5116
x-serial: 5965
set-cookie: Continent=AS; path=/; secure
set-cookie: Ak_City=TOKYO; path=/; secure
set-cookie: AKA_A2=A; expires=Fri, 18-Aug-2023 08:07:36 GMT; path=/; domain=justdial.com; secure; HttpOnly
server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=HIT
server-timing: edge; dur=1
x-jd-grn: 0.5ffc3b17.1692342456.248c13a
city: TOKYO
continent: AS
timing-allow-origin: *
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-check-cacheable: YES
x-akamai-request-id: 248c13a.4bb0504.3da38515.1dd6b96c
server-timing: ak_p; desc="1692342456314_389807199_38322490_26_11994_4_4_15";dur=1
```

**Expected Response**

```
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-powered-by: Next.js
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
zproduct_id: MjAweUhhMTMK
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors jdmart.com www.jdmart.com labs.jdmart.com sales.genio.in jdhealth.justdial.com www.jdomni.com
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-akamai-transformed: 9 - 0 pmb=mTOE,3mRUM,2
vary: Accept-Encoding
date: Fri, 18 Aug 2023 07:55:59 GMT
x-cache: TCP_MISS from a23-65-124-43.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (AkamaiGHost/11.2.2-50274567) (-)
x-cache-key: S/D/5965/800757/000/djskhdk-www.justdial.com/?akamai-transform=9
x-cache-key-extended-internal-use-only: S/D/5965/800757/000/djskhdk-www.justdial.com/?akamai-transform=9 vcd=5116
x-true-cache-key: /D/000/djskhdk-www.justdial.com/ vcd=5116
x-serial: 5965
set-cookie: _ctok=072d45ebe205e1692345359304x3tlmo3p3Crh9A86qEoljpppgvl8w4sBExtE; expires=Mon, 15 Aug 2033 07:55:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.justdial.com
set-cookie: web_visit=2023-08-18T07:55:59.304Z; expires=Mon, 15 Aug 2033 07:55:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.justdial.com
set-cookie: jd_www_nxt=1; expires=Mon, 15 Aug 2033 07:55:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.justdial.com
set-cookie: rfr=gen;  path=/; domain=.justdial.com
set-cookie: ppc=;Domain=.justdial.com
set-cookie: Continent=AS; path=/; secure
set-cookie: Ak_City=NEWDELHI; path=/; secure
set-cookie: AKA_A2=A; expires=Fri, 18-Aug-2023 08:55:59 GMT; path=/; domain=justdial.com; secure; HttpOnly
server-timing: edge; dur=19
server-timing: origin; dur=114
server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
x-jd-grn: 0.2b7c4117.1692345359.204b9051
city: NEWDELHI
continent: AS
timing-allow-origin:
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-check-cacheable: NO
x-akamai-request-id: 204b9051.4bb0504.3da38515.1dd6b96c
set-cookie: _abck=70A6760DB0052D4D917AED14F1D59655~-1~YAAQK3xBF2jct/6JAQAAP9ykBwqyy92iAPYrRVVvG1f686ef1yb+lIy/ln7nETHYLD1KLOILQdYXLhttgdS9JesxitDeJ+5/rnniNNDVUu2YWDjFzwXgKZDGo0eY7lHuQ3t3sH2m6Jmf9V9KZU2Zrvx5SQJo+vqkAtxMKcX4w1wM/rCqimG41G6ln6DXaqlWSWaSvEVSFif/O61iVe3wpJdsXEymEcIwMqVMn6s2W8f8TavRSe4HsUX6erdV6S6jtKuIouGGlptIN9fXQ0n/M9b4aQmhVfkYMdTKnI9sAja1rxKGAvQLarBOx1TEgBvGKMR1TMq2TIotAv7fzqy6NWBXn5wFdYfArysBKiiqlrC2auDGM3OcMkEQvoJLy0QMe0oBwA==~-1~-1~-1; Domain=.justdial.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 17 Aug 2024 07:55:59 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Secure
set-cookie: ak_bmsc=CA8C76AFFEA92A182E7A546537D84257~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQK3xBF2nct/6JAQAAP9ykBxSg7q5DvCs+3iL95seAS1ULhFhGAR6SW1F3cusy1kaSQQvnPGhjOFyQRbZIoieYirw82NFv3uMDKwMTxs2MRdC0+3GpZdt385hoezRIpCvxkx0sfkRkNuDmyl6Bwqny+qe119boaLrQm01U2KSyqFY+kSjMtDaEC3EDVQTZZza0xviMvuCqWWFvvj06GIRvpYfYyCkNWY9FRy5rk1zuxhhBBH49DEaoh3i82jzhjfLKeGVtVLX/oNUSknx0W4JDFD7DZXnR8hTZw61aoMhOTj4bzsYOYhQSpozMMyAZwp4NHpyLkGbNqEcLFtkrzLnmp5N73cFV56aX3n14My8qm2hoeDa9HMXIfSj3HEYfymn8UplPJcWuXbiC; Domain=.justdial.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 18 Aug 2023 09:55:59 GMT; Max-Age=7200; HttpOnly
set-cookie: bm_mi=4F8697355251C126B03262AB2EA3E57E~YAAQK3xBF2rct/6JAQAAP9ykBxTAYB0RNovZynZMYuAMNEazXGtgCZ1N8yuy7BpJv5g00M59XNzRisb0naTHl4hA5Fmn5k32D1ewwFoQyd/avqLzSIEIx8/9NXOzCsvWbedRuxru7HxCIjXbW/M+trly1cPyia0Dz/pKdLnUtdEC3pQpZwy4ACVvNOrIIrRP3ChWusmYz/Md9AlGiKBLGojr2FZkKbLIaVBxozLoCDbVpiJpMs33EoQZmJxdePIGb+ciaqn9NTE8CbvQsZ+lUv3IQ7GYIly9rNiWDyqfdoPMsTr7Ykhemvj0RE1xgGc=~1; Domain=.justdial.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 18 Aug 2023 07:55:59 GMT; Max-Age=0; Secure
set-cookie: bm_sz=E4D225B3BB757D8C7BF429CD2492D79C~YAAQK3xBF2vct/6JAQAAP9ykBxRpj+0fMq9gt0pZAW0ubjgQA0lGZTdg8zjq/RSnNWogRv8HgViynE0KX6AB5+aXJ1YfLtfxjwdKNOjOlSRh6VPI0CeRV0NwKgtfaZrpgkjrM/hOuBuvTRIh98ormUQ4IcUFq3GbPJ/YK8HCQvcf9W2n86rp796N2yGScRn6VdI9TfkEQ3HJUPgKcHLHJlt4OAaEj9XAw2tTKS/biKgAZH8GL1Lo6J5uqmxEX+U99YdiUQNkMlN0bEucqRgq+zriCFB1yY904PDopHZ3GTJ7LDw6bA==~4404793~3293489; Domain=.justdial.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 18 Aug 2023 11:55:59 GMT; Max-Age=14400
server-timing: ak_p; desc="1692345359215_390167595_541823057_13300_17585_42_0_15";dur=1
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried it step by step these are possible required headers. like cookie, timezone required and all. i'm attaching the both response from local as well as server. so you can easily check these headers are required or not.

Comment: Check the response and suggest the header which can i remove or add.

Comment: You can directly check this with this url 
https://paiza.io/projects/s8__Q_-i1kaa0GQCW7alLA

Comment: I had tried first with non-response header also but same issue coming. after that i have add more header according to cookie and response header but i want to find reason to why its block my request. i have also use with **Guzzle** and **HTTP_Request2** but still unable to find the solutions.

Comment: In that case, it seems likely you have been blocked by WAF policy (rate limiting, perhaps?). Do you have access to the Akamai account? If not, the only way you can find out why the request was denied is to get the account holder to check.

Answer (score -1):

I assume these tests are conducted repetitively and at a certain frequency. I notice that the site utilizes Akamai as a CDN, so it's possible that a security module is activated within the CDN or a WAF that inspects and validates suspicious requests. The HTTP 403 status code hints at this possibility.

If you have access to the site you wish to test, you could confirm this information.
When I run your code from my local machine, I receive an HTTP 200 status code.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to do this on local machine, I'm getting same response on local machine HTTP/2 200. Sure, Akamai use CDN but i didn't find more info to passed in header value so that it could be validate this request.

Comment: Certain CDNs and/or WAFs utilize intricate algorithms to detect bots and abnormal behaviors, tackling various challenges. I assume you would only have access to information about the active modules on the site being tested if that site is part of your company.

Alternatively, if you surpass the set request limit (Rate Limit), your access might get blocked. You can explore where that Rate Limit threshold lies to conduct tests without exceeding it and attain a 200 response code, effectively staying under the radar.